# Couchbase Community Upgrade - couchbase-server (3.x) conflicts with couchbase-server-community (4.x)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

I am trying to upgrade a Couchbase Community server that is currently running 3.0 to 4.0. I am using the 'Amazon Linux' on AWS, and have used the CentOS 6 build to upgrade from 2.5 to 3.0 - that upgrade was super smooth. According to the documentation, I should be able to go from 3.x to 4.x just fine as well.

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/install/upgrade-matrix.html:

```
Upgrade from the latest version 3.x directly to version 4.x using any supported upgrade strategy.
```

But I get the message

```
couchbase-server conflicts with couchbase-server-community-4.0.0-4051.x86_64
```

I have found that the `couchbase-server` name is now reserved for the enterprise edition, and `couchbase-server-community` is now used in 4.0 for the community edition, which would explain the conflict. https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-15716

Is this really an upgrade-breaking change? I cannot find any documentation on how to resolve this change short of uninstalling and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me and since you are on AWS, just spin up new instances, install Couchbase on them and do rebalances where you add one in and remove an old one (1 in, 1 out or 2 in, 2 out, etc.). With the same amount going in and out of the cluster, the cluster will do a swap rebalance which is the most efficient. All of this can be done while up and serving traffic. This is a very standard upgrade path and the recommended approach when in the cloud.

Once upgraded, discard the old instances. Yes you are running more instances at the same time during the upgrade, but for the cost of a few lattes you are upgraded smoothly.

Comment: Lacking a better solution, this is what I went with and it worked out fine. Still am surprised by the decision to break the upgrade path, but at least it is resolvable.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same conflict when trying to upgrade from Community version 3.0.1 to Community 4.0.0.

It is worth mentioning that if you uninstall the 3.0.1 version and then install 4.0.0, all your buckets and their data are kept. Maybe there are some cases where this would fail, always good to take a backup first, but in my case the transformation was smooth.

This was on my developer machine, for a cloud installation I really like the swap in/out which means you can do the upgrade without interruption of the service.